# Why do some foods do not taste good when eaten together that eaten separately would taste great

Tags: evolution, food

The way I understand it, 'good tasting food' is evolutionary concept e.g to be able to distinguish between high nutritional value foods and ones that have no nutritional value whatsoever.

So if well-prepared fish tastes well and so does some other food (birthday cake/[put food that would not go along]) on its own why then when mixed together they might taste bad. The mix has the same nutritional value, same proteins carbs, and fats, but they just don't go along.

**Why do some foods do not taste good when eaten together?**

Comment: Here are a few recipes: [Orange tilapia](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/237125/orange-tilapia/), [Honey orange fish filets](https://www.thespruceeats.com/honey-orange-fish-fillets-recipe-482668), [Baked Fish in Parchment with Orange and Olives](https://www.inspiredtaste.net/9317/baked-fish-with-orange-and-olives-recipe/), [White fish à l'orange](https://www.unjourunerecette.fr/recette-poisson-blanc-sauce-a-l-orange), and [fish with spices and orange juice](https://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_poisson-aux-epices-et-au-jus-d-orange_15067.aspx). I am VTC as primarily opinion based.

Comment: [Here](https://www.autostraddle.com/24-food-pairings-that-shouldnt-go-together-but-totally-do-300680/) is a list of surprising food pairings that people actually enjoy.

Comment: @Remi.b fish was just a (bad I suppose) example...

Comment: Can you find good examples?

Comment: @Remi.b I don't intend to... the question is not about some specific case. Also, your argument is defeated by yourself (by providing the link) as if some foods 'go together' that means that others don't...

Comment: My goal with this link was to show that even combinations that seem unintuitive might actually go well together. This link does not suggest that some food items fundamentally don't go together. I think that the fact that it is hard to find a good example shows that it is mainly a matter of culture preference and preparation. There is maybe nothing more fundamental than that. To me for example, sugar and meat were really the things that would be impossible to pair. My mind was changed when I started to travel a bit.

Comment: Your link is the other side of same coin... if something goes 'well' that can only mean that something does not...

Comment: If you could just come up with a few examples, that would clear up the argument. In all case, I'm done arguing on that matter. Good luck with your post.

Comment: Conditioning almost certainly plays a large role. Think of young children. Some are willing to put almost anything in their mouths (having been unconditioned), while others refuse to eat all but a select few foods until they're older (i.e after they've become conditioned either culturally or by what's available).